# Making an image black and white in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to make an image black and white in c#. Here is my code:

```
public static void SetGrayscale(Bitmap b)
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap) b;
        Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
        Color c;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
            {
                c = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                byte gray = (byte)(.299 * c.R + .587 * c.G + .114 * c.B);

                bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray));
            }
        }
        b = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();
    }       

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("D:\\users\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\aaa\\20130924_144411.tif"));
        byte[] pixels = ImageToByte(bm);

        SetGrayscale(bm);
    }
```

The problem is, it does not turn into black and white, it is still the same. Am i not saving the changed image? What can be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Bitmaps are disposable, you REALLY need to be using `using` blocks around a lot of those. Especially when you are working with GDI+ stuff, it is very easy to run out of resources before the garbage collector decides to collect the objects that went out of scope. Also `Bitmap temp = (Bitmap) b;` and `b = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();` are both totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you refering to that the file on disk doesn't change? You would have to save the grayscaled bitmap: `bm.Save("D:\\bitmap.tif");`

Comment: He also will need to return the modified bitmap, the copy he works on inside the function is a cloned copy so it would not be modifying the original.

Comment: also, this takes about 10 seconds, is it normal or do i need some optimization?

Comment: @panpa there are faster ways to work with bitmaps but it requires more complicated code. It involves using [Bitmap.LockBits(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx), the MSDN page has a example.

Comment: @panpa - "yes, now it is saving thank you" - you should accept this answer.